# Cambiar el tamaño de los bordes

Tags: wordpress, wamp

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Verán, tengo una página de Wordpress la cual tiene un fondo blanco con bordes verdes, pero no quiero esos bordes.
¿Como hago para que solo quede el fondo blanco?
Estoy utilizando el tema Catch Box.
He probado a escribir código en "CSS Adicional", pero por ahora no me ha servido.

Comment: Tienes que modificar la hoja de estilo (CSS) de tu sitio web

Comment: @Reynald0 ¿Y como hago eso? He probado a hacer modificaciones en CSS adicional, pero no he logrado nada. Probé ahí a cambiar el width, pero solo desplaza la página.

Answer (score 0):

He inspeccionado el código de mi página, descubriendo que la parte blanca tiene un id llamado "page".
En el menú CSS Adicional, he puesto este código:

> `#page{width:95%;}`

Aún hay cosas por arreglar, pero con esto mi principal problema esta arreglado.